# How to join two tables in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have two tables,

```
SET search_path = public;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS changelog
(
    id          BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    object_type TEXT,
    object_id   BIGINT,
    parent_type TEXT,
    parent_id   BIGINT,
    action      TEXT,
    field       TEXT,
    old_value   TEXT,
    new_value   TEXT,
    comment_id  INTEGER,
    created_on  TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    created_by  BIGINT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS changelog_comments
(
    id         INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    comment    TEXT,
    created_on TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    created_by BIGINT
);

SET search_path = DEFAULT;
```

I want to implement a search method for the changelog which returns the fields

```
"objectType"
"objectId"
"parentType"
"parentId"
"action"
"field"
"oldValue"
"newValue"
"comment"
"createdBy"
"createdOn"
```

as you can see the result comes from the join of the two tables.

I found https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html but to be honest, didn't get that how can I achieve what I need.

I thought something like the following could be helpful

```
type ChangelogResponseItem struct {
    ObjectType string     `json:"objectType"`
    ObjectID   uuid.UUID  `json:"objectId"`
    ParentType string     `json:"parentType"`
    ParentID   uuid.UUID  `json:"parentId"`
    Action     string     `json:"action"`
    Field      *string    `json:"field"`
    OldValue   *string    `json:"oldValue"`
    NewValue   *string    `json:"newValue"`
    Comment    *string    `json:"comment"`
    CreatedBy  *uint64    `json:"createdBy"`
    CreatedOn  *time.Time `json:"createdOn"`
}
```

**The question is that how can get what I mentioned from the mentioned tables in GORM?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to combine `Joins` and `Select` methods to get what you want. Based on your table, it would look something like this:

```
list := []ChangelogResponseItem{}
tx := db.Table("changelog").
         Joins("INNER JOIN changelog_comments cc ON cc.id = changelog.comment_id").
         Select("changelog.objectType, changelog.object_type, changelog.object_id, changelog.parent_type, changelog.parent_id, changelog.action, changelog.field, changelog.old_value, changelog.new_value, cc.comment, changelog.created_on, changelog.created_by").
         Find(&list)
if tx.Error != nil {
  // handle error
}
```

This is just to return the data, a search would include additional `Where` methods.

**EDIT:**

Solution with a preload option:

Structs:

```
type ChangelogComment struct {
  ID uint64 `json:"id"`
  Comment string `json:"comment"`
}

type Changelog struct {
    ObjectType string     `json:"objectType"`
    ObjectID   uuid.UUID  `json:"objectId"`
    ParentType string     `json:"parentType"`
    ParentID   uuid.UUID  `json:"parentId"`
    Action     string     `json:"action"`
    Field      *string    `json:"field"`
    OldValue   *string    `json:"oldValue"`
    NewValue   *string    `json:"newValue"`
    CommentID    uint64    `json:"comment_id"`
    Comment    *ChangelogComment `json:"comment"` 
    CreatedBy  *uint64    `json:"createdBy"`
    CreatedOn  *time.Time `json:"createdOn"`
}
```

Code with the `Preload` method:

```
list := []Changelog{}
tx := db.Preload("Comment").Find(&list)
if tx.Error != nil {
  // handle error
}
```

Please note that in this case, you will have a different JSON object, the structure od the object will not be flat, because you will have a `comment` field as well.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and answer. one question, how we can skip the `select` statement and provide a better way to return get data? is that possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure it can, because your `ChangelogResponseItem` struct is basically a custom view that is using multiple tables. If it didn't have the `Comment` field in it, you could have done it without the `Select` method. Also, you can write the `Select("changelog.*, cc.comment")` like this.

Comment: thanks for the quick, could you please help me with it? ( please provide a struct that supports what I needed, I can redefine the struct to make the query simpler.)?

Comment: I meant, finally I want to return response that way, but how can we make it easier?

Comment: I've added a solution with the `Preload` option and a few struct modifications

Comment: @EminLaletovic Do not use `Preload` unless the amount of records is small and limited. `Preload` generates an `IN` clause that grows with the amount of records in your origin table.

Comment: There are options to limit the number of records loaded when there are many records in the origin table. With custom `Preload`, the records can be limited, ordered, and filtered as needed.  
https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Custom-Preloading-SQL