# Correct way to use join in gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have two structs,

```
type Table1 struct {
    Username string `gorm:"primaryKey"` 
    Attr1    string
}

type Table2 struct {
    Username string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Attr2    int
}
```

If I join these two tables, and use `gorm.Scan(&model)` to retrieve the value from database, I will not be able to get values from both struct.

If I define a composite struct, e.g

```
type Table1 struct {
   ...
   Table2
}
```

Then all the fields from Table2 will be created in Table1.

I'm not sure what's the best practice here, any suggestions?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221270/how-to-join-two-tables-in-gorm answer your question?

Comment: @BillKarwin Nope, I know how join works, but my question is about defining golang struts, and the best practice